# Problem with list in Lisp

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I am trying to write a simple procedure in Lisp to insert an element into binary search tree.

I represented the tree as a list:

- the first element in the tree is the root
- the second element is the left sub-tree
- the third element is the right sub-tree

This is my code:

```
(define Insert
  (lambda (x T) 
    (if (null? T) 
        (list x '() '())
        (if (> x (car T)) 
            (list (car T)
                  (cadr T)
                  (Insert x (list (caddr T))))
            (list (car T)
                  (Insert x (cadr T))
                  (list (caddr T)))))))
```

When I call the procedure like this: `(Insert 2 '(4 '(2 '() '() ) '()))`, I get a problem with ">" because the second argument isn't a real number, but I don't know why.

The exception:

```
>: expects type <real number> as 2nd argument, given: quote; other arguments were: 2
```

However, when I call the procedure like this: `(Insert 2 ( list 4 (list 2 '() '() ) '()))`,
it works successfully.

Why?

I know that `'(1 '() '())` and  `(list 1 '() '())` are equals, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(1 '())` is equivalent to `(list 1 (list 'quote nil))`. I suspect that if you drop the "internal" quote characters, you will be fine.

So, the quoted expression that generates an expression that is equal to `(list 1 '() '())` is `'(1 () ())`.

Comment: Also, `nil` in Lisp is `'()` in Scheme.

Comment: @erijang: Ah, I thought nil and () were the same, but nil and #f were different.

Answer (score 2):

No, `quote` and `list` are not the same at all.  The meaning of `'foo` is `(quote foo)`.

`'(a b c)` is exactly `(quote (a b c))`, that is, a *list literal* (the `quote` operator prevents the list from being evaluated).  It is comparable to `"a b c"`, which is a *string literal* or `5`, which is a *number literal*.  Operations that modify literals have undefined effects, as you may recognize immediately when you see some nonsense like `(setf 3 4)`.

`(list a b c)`, on the other hand, creates ("conses") a new list from the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

I am sure that if you clear up your confusion about `quote` and `list`, you will be able to correct your code.