# Only by using cons car cdr

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

How do I get elements from 2nd to 7th from a list, using *only* the following three functions:

- `cons`
- `car`
- `cdr`

Example;

```
> (two-to-seven (list 8 9 5 1 0 3 6 2 4))
> (9 5 1 0 3 6)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> (define (t2s xs)
    (cons (car (cdr xs)) (cons (car (cdr (cdr xs))) (cons (car (cdr (cdr (cdr xs)))) (cons (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr xs))))) (cons (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr xs)))))) (cons (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr xs))))))) (list))))))))
> (t2s (list 8 2 5 4 0 3 6 1 1))
(2 5 4 0 3 6)
```

Comment: (cons (cadr xs) (cons (caddr xs) (cons (cadddr xs) (cons (car (cddddr xs)) (cons (cadr (cddddr xs)) (cons (caddr (cddddr xs)) empty))))))  a bit shorter :P

Comment: @nvm: Yes, a bit shorter, but no longer conformant to the "only `cons`, `car`, and `cdr`" requirement. :-P

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: didn't take that too literally

Comment: @borku: You can use `'()` in place of `(list)`. They are identical.

Comment: @borku: yes you can, also consider marking this answer as a solution

Comment: @borku @Chris @nvm: *"Could I use '()"* Probably not, I wouldn't depend on `'()` (`quote`), because `quote` and `list` are not the same, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625645/problem-with-list-in-lisp/4626514#4626514).

Comment: @nmv Sorry, this is my first day here. I am not familiar with answer vote system ;(

Comment: '() is equal to (list). I don't know where you got (quote), you probably misread our answers or the link you are pointing to.  > (equal? '() (list))
#t

Comment: @borku: under the number of points this answer got 2 there is a check mark. press it to turn it green on all your answered questions. You can upvote many answers for being helpful by pressing the triangle above the number but you can only chose one answer as the right one.

Comment: @nvm: (equal? '(+ 2 3 4) (list + 2 3 4)) => #f

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: we were talking about the empty list. And you don't make a compelling argument by using this 
> (list + 1 2 3)
(#<procedure:+> 1 2 3)
> (list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
> (equal? '(1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))
#t

Comment: @nvm: `'()` accoring to abovementioned post is exactly `(quote ())`, and thus it's *list literal*, not a *list*. See [Literal expressions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_4.1.2) in R^5RS.

Comment: I assume this is dead at this point but nvm was right.  You can just sub out for the definitions in nvm's answer.  He's just using shorthand:
cadr x = car (cdr x)
caddr x = car (cdr (cdr x))

Answer (score 0):

My solution. You might want to initialize the acumulator ( `acum` ) with 1, and/or use  `>=` and `<=`. You provided no output.

```
(define (test-get start stop tlst)
(define acum 0)
(define (get-elems lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) empty)
          ((and (symbol? (car lst))
                (< acum stop)
                (> acum start))
                    (set! acum (+ 1 acum)) 
                    (cons (car lst) (get-elems (cdr lst))))
          ((symbol? (car lst)) 
                (set! acum (+ 1 acum))
                (get-elems (cdr lst)))
          (else (append (get-elems (car lst)) (get-elems (cdr lst))))))

  (get-elems tlst))
```

Sample output

```
> (test-get 0 3 '(a (b) (c (d)) e (((f))) (h (i (j))) (k l)))
(b c)
> (test-get 2 6 '(a (b) (c (d)) e (((f))) (h (i (j))) (k l)))
(d e f)
> (test-get 2 7 '(a (b) (c (d)) e (((f))) (h (i (j))) (k l)))
(d e f h)
```

And if you're bothered by the `append` showing there you could replace it with your own using `cons`, `cdr`, `car`

```
(define (my-append l1 l2)
    (if (null? l1)
      l2
      (cons (car l1) (my-append (cdr l1) l2))))
```

To also get rid of the `set!` so we'll be more in the bounds of functional programming (not tested):

```
(define (test-get start stop tlst)
(define (liniarize lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) empty)
          ((symbol? (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (liniarize (cdr lst))))
          (else (my-append (liniarize (car lst)) (liniarize (cdr lst))))))

(define (take-elems lst acum)
    (cond ((null? lst) empty)
          ((and (< acum stop)
                (> acum start)) (cons (car lst) (take-elems (cdr lst) (+ 1 acum))))
          (else (take-elems lst (+ 1 acum))))) 


  (take-elems (liniarize tlst) 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, but the task was to solve this problem only by using car, cons and cdr : )